# To set symfony validators for custom HTML elements

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms

I have created custom HTML form elements to take inputs from user, and i am not using the Symfony Form. i know that it keep me out of Symfony form validation system, `Is there any way to use custom HTML element and get Symfony Form validation on that elements`.
I have used Symfony forms and i know how to use validators, but this time i am using custom HTML forms as Symfony form was not giving me that flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The *More on Symfony* book has a [guide to writing your own validator](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/05-Custom-Widgets-and-Validators#chapter_05_building_a_simple_widget_and_validator).  If you can say what you want the validator to achieve, I might be able to give you some pointers about how to implement it.

You do not need to use the form framework to use the validator framework, but I do wonder why you chose not to...

Comment: i am building a online question answer form, which will change depending upon the question type, the forms will be loaded dynamically and the validators(some validators) were not working when i generated forms dynamically in controller... hope you understood.. and thank you @lonesomeday